# Linear Algebra, Base and Dimension proof

Tags: linear-algebra

A,B  matrix nxn  so that AB=0  proof that rank(A)+rank(B)=n
I don't know even where to start, or look for.

Comment: What if $A$ and $B$ are both the zero matrix? Are you sure of the statement?

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the problem is the following:

Given two $(n\times n)$-matrices $A$, $B$ with $AB=0$, prove that ${\rm rank}(A) +{\rm rank}(B)\leq n$.

A hint:  $AB=0$ means the following: Any vector in ${\rm im}(B)$ is annihilated by $A$, in other words: ${\rm ker}(A)\supset{\rm im}(B)$. What does this imply for the dimensions of the involved spaces and the ranks of the involved maps/matrices ?